# How to randomize objects/links in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am self-learning HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and am trying to put something together.

I would like to have 100 clickable images/links (just buttons of the same image really).  I would like a percentage of the buttons to link to one page, and the remainder to link to another page.  This would be blind to the user until they clicked it.

Each time the page reloads I would like the images/links to be randomized for where they are.

I know I can generate a random number in JS with `Math.random()`, but can't seem to figure out how to do what I am describing above.  I know I can learn best by doing, so I was seeing if anybody had any guidance.

Comment: It would help to show a small example of your HTML and Javascript. Most likely, you'd want to call a Javascript function when clicking a link, and that function would randomly select a URL.

Comment: if you use  flex, you can also random the order position for each button

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions should have a [mimimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows what you have tried and where you need help. There are many different ways to approach your problem and any answer will depend on what results you are looking for.

Comment: I know I can learn best by doing, so I was seeing if anybody had any guidance.

You say that but where's your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    for(var i=0;i<100;i++)
        CreateButtons();
});

function CreateButtons()
{
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");   // Create a <button> element
    btn.innerHTML = "Try your luck";                   // Insert text

    btn.onclick = RedirectLink;
    document.body.appendChild(btn);  
}

function RedirectLink()
{
    var redirectLink = "";
    var randomNumber = Math.random();
    if(randomNumber % 2 == 0)
        redirectLink = "https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp";
    else
        redirectLink = "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp";
    window.location.replace(redirectLink);
}
```

`CreateButtons()` will create list of buttons for you and each time the page is loaded and a button is clicked `RedirectLink()` will randomize where to redirect the user to.

Here are some links that I refered to come up with this answer:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp

Comment: This is awesome and thanks for the links for the answer - will certainly help to learn.